# Grab an event in an intermediary handler, hold it in a property, then dispatch it later and still get the .target?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

Is it possible to grab an event, hold it in a class property, do some action, then, when that action is complete, dispatch an event and then retrieve the original event.target in the listener?

I am trying to avoid using a custom event for now, as it is giving me massive amounts of heartburn when dispatching it from a loaded SWF.

Here is some code (that doesn't work) that hopefully will help to understand what I am attempting to do:

```
package
{
    import fl.transitions.easing.Regular;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        protected var _event:Event;

        public function Document():void
        {
            initLoader();
        }

        protected function initLoader():void
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest('some_url.xml'));
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, intermediaryHandler);
        }

        protected function intermediaryHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            _event = event;
            doSomeAction();
        }

        protected function doSomeAction():void
        {
            var tween:Tween = new Tween(someObject, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0, 1, 5);
            tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenHandler);
        }

        protected function tweenHandler(event:TweenEvent):void
        {
            /*
             * Imagine some object is listening to this class for Event.COMPLETE.
             * I would like to retrieve the event.target that I could have retrieved
             * in the `intermediaryHandler()` method, in the listener to the following
             * event being dispatched:
             */
            dispatchEvent(_event);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to stash the event in a class variable, and then access it later, but the cherry on the icing would be to get it from the event fired withing `tweenHandler()` in my example above.

**Edit**
Well, it doesn't look possible (thanks @bhups for the explanation). I am currently storing the retrieved event in a property `_event` and then getting it at a later time when I need it. This seems to work, but isn't wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible. Whenever you are re-dispatching an Event, then Flash Runtime makes a clone of it and dispatches it into the Event Flow. And once Event goes to the Event Flow then, its properties can not be altered. `target` and `currentTarget` are `read-only` properties of an Event object. So without using a CustomEvent it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do.
What problem exactly you're facing when using Custom Event?

Comment: Thanks @bhups. I receive error #1034 when I try to dispatch a custom event from a loaded SWF. I have not been able to solve the issue as of yet. It is similar to when I try to get or set a custom type within a loaded SWF. I think it might have something to do with the security sandbox, but I am not sure.

Comment: I may have found two different solutions here: http://www.jeffdepascale.com/index.php/flash/custom-events-in-loaded-swf-files/ and here: http://www.jeffdepascale.com/index.php/flash/dispatching-custom-events-between-child-swfs-in-as3/